# How to turn off FancyBox on certain images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Can anyone help me turn off FancyBox on certain images? I've tried a million different options here but haven't made much progress. The images I'm working on are in the WowSlider banner here: http://www.freemanfoxx.com. The problem, as you'll see is that some images have no href location and when they are clicked fancy box is loading an error page. If we could either change the class dynamically or do something else to stop fancybox from loading that would be a miracle.

Thank you!!!!

Images are loaded dynamically via PHP:

```
if (empty($descr)){
echo "<a href='#'>";}

else {
echo "<a rel=group1 href=";
    echo $descr;
    echo " target=_blank>"; }
?><img src="<?php echo $wpimage[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $wpimage[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $wpimage[2]; ?>" alt="" title="" id="wows<?php echo $image->ID; ?>">
<?php
if (empty($descr)){
echo "</a>";}

else {
echo "</a>";}
```

FancyBox Loads based on:

```
    $("a.wow-fancy").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'width': 895,
    'height': 600,
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

The class "cs-wowslider-images-new" is added to the images via javascript through this file: http://freemanfoxxrealty.com/wp-content/themes/freemanfoxx/js/2wows-squares.js

---

### UPDATE

I think I might be able to accomplish this by dynamically removing a class but it doesn't seem to be working.. any thoughts?

```
    if(("a.wow-fancy").attr('href') = "#"){
    $(this).removeClass("wow-fancy");
    alert('hi');
}
```

Comment: Couple of things, `=` should be `==` I believe, and that code should run after the wowslider has finished adding its respective classes. Also you need to loop through all your `a.wow-fancy`s, with something like `$.each('a.wow-fancy')` Not sure where you are adding this `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One option is:**

Change the PHP to not include the `href` tag at all, if the `$descr` is empty (if that works for you). Then:

`$('a[href].cs-wowslider-images-new').fancybox({...`

Sort of like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/q9Tpd/

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to edit the html, you could always add a class-name to the images you don't want to use fancybox on and use the selector:

```
    $("a.cs-wowslider-images-new:not('.noFancyBoxOnThisClassName')").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'width': 895,
    'height': 600,
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

---

**Edited** in response to question edits by OP.

To test whether the `href` is merely `'#'` and, if it is, remove the `wow-fancy` class:

```
$('a.wow-fancy').each(
    function(){
        if (this.href == '#') {
            $(this).removeClass('wow-fancy');
        }
    });
```

Comment: classes are added dynamically.. what about changing the class dynamically based on the HREF attrib like I listed above? I tried it but it doesn't work.. maybe my code has an error? What do you think, David? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my condition:

```
$('.content img')
  .not('[hidden]')
  .not('.group-picture img, .post-gallery img')
  .not('.no-fancybox')
  .each(function () {
    var $image = $(this);
    var imageTitle = $image.attr('title');
    var $imageWrapLink = $image.parent('a');

    if ($imageWrapLink.size() < 1) {
        var imageLink = ($image.attr('data-original')) ? this.getAttribute('data-original') : this.getAttribute('src');
      $imageWrapLink = $image.wrap('<a href="' + imageLink + '"></a>').parent('a');
    }

    $imageWrapLink.addClass('fancybox fancybox.image');
    $imageWrapLink.attr('rel', 'group');

    if (imageTitle) {
      $imageWrapLink.append('<p class="image-caption">' + imageTitle + '</p>');

      //make sure img title tag will show correctly in fancybox
      $imageWrapLink.attr('title', imageTitle);
    }
  });

$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
  }
});
```

Just add that `.not('.no-fancybox')`, and later add the `no-fancybox` class to the `<img>` tag you do not need fancybox could be OK.

Actually, this pice of code comes from Hexo blog theme NexT (`themes/next/source/js/src/utils.js`)